# How to remove series value from hover tooltip apex charts pie

Tags: charts, apexcharts

[image]

I want to just remove the number `33` from this, I want it to just show `series-4`

[image]

what to do to hide it from tooltip?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can [customize the tooltip](https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/tooltip/) by providing formatters. In this case, you'll want to override both the title (`seriesName`) and the y value label. In place of the y value, return a blank string.

You'll need to provide a formatter for the title as well because not doing so will default to the series title being shown followed by a colon.

```
  tooltip: {
    y: {
      formatter: function(val) {
        return ''
      },
      title: {
        formatter: function (seriesName) {
          return seriesName
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks. i followed this but title is still being shown followed by a colon!

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the tooltips options to:

```
tooltip: {
  enabled: false
}
```

That did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `name:""`, here is sample code,

```
series: [{
    name: "",
    data: [{
        x: "2018-09-10",
        y: 120
      }, {
        x: "2018-09-11",
        y: 480
      }]
    }
]
```